# Collect stream only if allMatch filter and process stream once in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following stream code:

```
List<Data> results = items.stream()
   .map(item -> requestDataForItem(item))
   .filter(data -> data.isValid())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

Data requestDataForItem(Item item) {
   // call another service here
}
```

The problem is that I want to call
`requestDataForItem` only when all elements in the stream are valid.
For example,
if the first item is invalid I don't wont to make the call for any element in the stream.

There is `.allMatch` in the stream API,
but it returns a `boolean`. 
I want to do the same as `.allMatch` than
`.collect` the result when everything matched.
Also, I want to process stream only once,
with two loops it is easy.

Is this possible with the Java Streams API?

Comment: Just check if `results.size() == items.size()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be a job for Java 9:

```
List<Data> results = items.stream()
    .map(item -> requestDataForItem(item))
    .takeWhile(data -> data.isValid())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This operation will stop at the first invalid element. In a sequential execution, this implies that no subsequent `requestDataForItem` calls are made. In a parallel execution, some additional elements might get processed concurrently, before the operation stops, but that’s the price for efficient parallel processing.

In either case, the result list will only contain the elements before the first encountered invalid element and you can easily check using `results.size() == items.size()` whether all elements were valid.

---

In Java 8, there is no such simple method and using an additional library or rolling out your own implementation of `takeWhile` wouldn’t pay off considering how simple the non-stream solution would be

```
List<Data> results = new ArrayList<>();
for(Item item: items) {
    Data data = requestDataForItem(item);
    if(!data.isValid()) break;
    results.add(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically use `.allMatch` then collect if `.allMatch` returns true, *but* then you'd be processing the collection twice. There's no way to do what you're trying to do with the streams API directly.

You could create a method to do this for you and simply pass your collection to it as opposed to using the stream API. This is slightly less elegant than using the stream API but more efficient as it processes the collection only once.

```
List<Data> results = getAllIfValid(
         items.stream().map(item -> 
             requestDataForItem(item).collect(Collectors.toList())
);

public List<Data> getAllIfValid(List<Data> items) {
    List<Data> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Data d : items) {
        if (!d.isValid()) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        results.add(d);
    }
    return results;
}
```

This will return all the results if every element passes and only processes the `items` collection once. If any fail the `isValid()` check, it'll return an empty list as you want all or nothing. Simply check to see if the returned collection is empty to see whether or not all items passed the `isValid()` check.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a two step process:

1. test if allMatch returns true.
2. If it does return true, do the collect with a second stream.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my questions. Two steps process in clear, but it is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
List<Data> result = new ArrayList<>();
boolean allValid = items.stream()
    .map(item -> requestDataForItem(item))
    .allMatch(data -> data.isValid() && result.add(data));
if (!allValid)
    result.clear();
```

Comment: The API makes no guarantees that `allMatch` will evaluate all elements in the encounter order.